# Liquibase "Could not release lock" error

Tags: java, sql, foreign-keys, liquibase

While running a Liquibase changeset I get the following error: 
`Could not release lock`. The base exception is actually an `SQLException: Connection is closed!`.

The changeset contains a `renameColumn`.

```
<changeSet author="me" id="renameaTob">
    <renameColumn newColumnName="b" oldColumnName="a" columnDataType="BIGINT(19)" tableName="aTable" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact that the column to be renamed was part of a foreign key constraint.

The solution was to drop first the constraint and then add it again with the new column name. But if all these operations are done in the same changeset, the result is no different. So it has to be split into two changesets: first, dropping the constraint and renaming the column and second, recreating the foreign key constraint.

```
<changeSet author="me" id="renameaTob">
    <dropForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="aTable" constraintName="a_c_fk2"/>
    <renameColumn newColumnName="b" oldColumnName="a" columnDataType="BIGINT(19)" tableName="aTable" />
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="me" id="addFkAgain">
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="b"
            baseTableName="aTable" constraintName="b_c_fk2"
            deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="NO ACTION"
            onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="c" referencedTableName="refTable" />
</changeSet>
```

I think it is also possible to use only one changeset and add `runInTransaction='false'`, but this is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: I would recommend making the changes as 3 separate changeSets. The same changes are made, but since Liquibase will track each separately you don't run into a problem if the first half of a changeSet passes (dropForeignKey) but the second fails (renameColumn). If that happens, on the next update liquibase will still try to run the dropForeignKeyConstraint but it will fail with an OBJECT NOT EXISTS error.

Comment: RunInTransaction won't affect these particular changeSets because all the statements auto-commit on most databases. The main use for runInTransaction=false is for databases that don't allow DDL statements in a transaction.